# How do I stop biblatex printing the bibtex key?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I think I'm looking for the equivalent of `isbn=false` which stops the ISBN number being printed, but for stopping the bibtex key being printed. The problem is that currently my bibliography contains all the bibtex keys. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{georgescu-roegen_entropy_1971,
address = {Cambridge, MA},
title = {The entropy law and the economic process},
publisher = {Harvard University Press},
author = {Georgescu-Roegen, Nicholas},
year = {1971},
note = {bibtex: georgescu-roegen\_entropy\_1971}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliography{bibligraphy.bib}                  
\begin{document}
This is a book (\cite{georgescu-roegen_entropy_1971}).
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

prints:

> This is a book (Georgescu-Roegen 1971).
>
> **References**
>
> Georgescu-Roegen, Nicholas (1971). *The entropy law and the economic process.* bibtex: georgescu-roegen_entropy_1971. Cambridge, MA: Harvard University Press.

Comment: biblatex doesn't do this normally. Show your bib-entry.

Comment: `bib` is not the same like `bbl`. It seems you have added the key to the `note` field. But to reproduce this, I need the entry from the `bib` file. Please show us a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: Thanks, yes it looks like it. I'm using Zotero, so the note field is generated automatically. Is this then a Zotero problem, do you think?

Comment: If you don't want to see that, then this is indeed a Zotero problem. You should be able to tell Zotero to stop doing that.

Comment: You probably want to export with *Better biblatex*, and not the standard *biblatex*. The [better Bib(La)TeX plugin](https://github.com/retorquere/zotero-better-bibtex/wiki) for Zotero lets you specify a key manually by writing `bibtex: ...` in the *Extra* field, but it removes that if you export with notes.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to tell Zotero not to occupy the `note` field for the key. But If you cannot do so, and if you are not able to remove the `note` field using, e.g., `sed`, you can switch from backend `bibtex` to `biber` and use source mapping to remove the `note` fields from all entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{georgescu-roegen_entropy_1971,
address = {Cambridge, MA},
title = {The entropy law and the economic process},
publisher = {Harvard University Press},
author = {Georgescu-Roegen, Nicholas},
year = {1971},
note = {bibtex: georgescu-roegen\_entropy\_1971}
}
\end{filecontents}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=note,null]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
This is a book (\cite{georgescu-roegen_entropy_1971}).
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: removed key from note]

after running `pdflatex`, `biber` and two times `pdflatex`.

Note: Backend `bibtex` does not support source mapping! This is one of several advantages of using `biber`.