# Wanted: question mark instead of bibtex key for missing citations (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex, formatting, biber, default

Instead of having the citation key showing up in the document for missing references, I want to only have [?], as it is the case when using the default bibtex without biblatex. This behavior is driving me crazy, as it messes up all the formatting (especially in tables). I want to focus on writing and only later on deal with the erroneous citations.

This question is related to

[How do I stop biblatex printing the bibtex key?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367753/how-do-i-stop-biblatex-printing-the-bibtex-key)

and its MWE can be used. However, as pointed out beforehand, I *want* the question mark in the text *instead* of the citation key to not mess up the formatting (for missing citations).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since version 3.12 `biblatex` has had the semi-internal macro `\abx@missing@entry` which can be redefined as follows

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\def\abx@missing@entry#1{\abx@missing{??}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,appleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Missing entry key is shown as <code>??</code> and not as <code>appleby</code>]

The default definition of `\abx@missing@entry` is

```
\def\abx@missing@entry#1{%
  \abx@missing{#1}}
```

where `#1` is the unknown entrykey. See https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/8df18a8725f8ba150c142443f64024c7ad8966c6

---

With older versions of `biblatex` you could use

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@citeadd#1{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}
    {\edef\blx@realkey{\csuse{blx@keyalias@\the\c@refsection @#1}}}
    {\def\blx@realkey{#1}}%
  \expandafter\blx@getrefcontext\expandafter{\blx@realkey}% needed for \ifdata
  \expandafter\blx@citation\expandafter{\blx@realkey}\blx@msg@cundefon
  \expandafter\blx@ifdata\expandafter{\blx@realkey}
    {\advance\blx@tempcnta\@ne
     \listeadd\blx@tempa{\blx@realkey}}
    {\ifnum\blx@tempcntb>\z@\multicitedelim\fi
     \expandafter\abx@missing\expandafter{??}%<- the change is here
     \advance\blx@tempcntb\@ne}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: perfect, nice! thank you so much. this is exactly what I have been searching for. there should be an option for the package to have that kind of behavior.

Comment: @user26372 I agree. See the edit.