# How to force biblatex to show question mark when there is a missing citation?

Tags: biblatex

I have the opposite of the usual problem: I want to get back the question marks for missing citations!

With `bibtex`, when there is a key that does not match any entry, in the generate pdf file there is a "`?`" instead of the citation. `Biblatex` instead puts the `\cite`  command's argument in bold face when the argument isn't found in the bibliography.

Is there any way that I can get the question mark behavior with `biblatex`? I just find it easier to identify my possible mistakes or automate a sanity check with a simple search for question marks. Also with some citation styles, this `biblatex` behavior is recipe for disaster.

#### edit:

For the sake of completeness, I use `biber` as the back-end. Also, I know I can check the log or ask `biber` to do some validations. Still I prefer the question marks.

Comment: Tada: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/433789/35864!

Comment: @moewe And I was so proud of my google-fu skill... Thanks a lot mate :) Please do mark this as duplicate.

Comment: Done! The obvious search terms "undefined" and "question mark" will generate a lot of false hits here, so as always it was easier to find the answer when you already know roughly what it should look like.